# ResquestMapping for specific package

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm looking for a solution to have a specific mapping on a package in Spring 3 application.

I have the normal mapping, like this:

```
@Controller
public class Home {

    @RequestMapping(value ="/")
    public void home() {
        ...
    }
}
```

and another like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value ="/api")
public class ApiResource {

    @RequestMapping(value ="/resource")
    public void home() {
         ...
    }
}
```

The problem is: I have a lot of resources mapped on **/api** context.

Is any way to tell to Spring that all classes in package `com.example.api` will be acessible in `/api` context? Or something that I don't need to put `@RequestMapping(value = "/api")` on each `Controller` class for this api?

I need to still using the normal context, at `"/*"` for another `Controllers`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved creating an annotation for this kind of `Controller` at `api` package.

```
    @ApiController
    public class ApiResource {

        @RequestMapping(value ="/resource")
        public void home() {
             ...
        }
    }
```

The interface was declared like this:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
public @interface ApiController {

}
```

And worked pretty well, mapping all requests annotated with `@ApiController` to `/api/*` path.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it in applicationContext.xml file with following :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
<property name="mappings">
  <map>
     <entry key="/doSomething/**" value-ref="controllerA"/>
     <entry key="/other Thing/**" value-ref="controllerB"/>
  </map>
</property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. In this approach, I need to put every class in this mapping? Or the entry key will accept just a package?

Comment: I tried and not solve =( I still need to put all classes on application context.